# Redirect only the root URL to some other file in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am using firebase hosting for my web application.

I want to show lp.html at the root of my URL and index.html at everywhere else. To achieve this, I have configured my firebase.json like this:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build/es6-bundled",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/",
        "destination": "/lp.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But when I user firebase serve and open http://localhost:5000/, I see the contents from index.html. How can I have the root URL point to lp.html?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out for some reason, firebase picks to serve index.html at the root URL by default without consulting the firebase.json. To avoid this, I changed the name of my index.html file to app.html, and everything worked as expected.

Comment: I had the same problem. Thanks for your solution, it also worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me too. Is this documented anywhere in Firebase?

Comment: @IndikaK I did not find this anywhere in the documentation. I just figured this out by common sense lol

Comment: This is not true. You can use `redirects` in `firebase.json`.

Answer (score 9):

Going to add some more info because the selected answer isn't 100% correct. First, it's important to clarify the difference between `rewrites` vs `redirects`. With `rewrites` specified in firebase.json, Firebase will indeed only act on your rewrite rule if the specified file isn't found first. Here is the relevant section from the doc:

> Firebase Hosting only applies a rewrite rule if a file or directory does not exist at the specified source. When a rule is triggered, the browser returns the actual content of the specified destination file instead of an HTTP redirect.

`redirects` that you specify in firebase.json are something different. They actually will send a 301 or 302 redirect to the user's browser to cause the browser to request the URL at the destination location. Not sure what the original post actually wanted the browser's URL to look like, but this would also work:

```
"redirects":[ 
  {
    "source": "/",
    "destination": "/lp.html",
    "type": 301
  }
],
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]
```

Comment: But redirect was not what I wanted. I wanted to show `/` in the URL of the browser while showing the `lp.html`.